# How can I do a messagebox in asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, namespaces, controller, messagebox

I've been trying to do a messagebox in a controller in asp.net mvc, but every time I type MessageBox or MsgBox it doesn't give me the option to import a namespace...

What can I use that would be similar to a MessageBox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Message box can be shown using Javascript, you can write your own HtmlHelper for this or have a partial which takes the message as input and diplays it, in this way you can reuse your partial

Answer (score 7):

the MessageBox functionality is provided by the System.Windows library which is not available in the ASP.NET MVC context, since your site is running within a browser.

Instead, you should use a javascript library to show a message box.

You could use the following in order to display a message box

alert('Hi there')

Comment: well I need to be able to see what's going on in the backend, I can't really alert backend variables from javascript while the backend code is running.

Comment: you mean you want the user to take a decision which the backend will use in order to render or work on something?

Answer (score 1):

you could render out a script tag as a actionresult that has

alert('{0}'); where the placeholder is you message

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using the [jQuery UI dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/). It's incredibly easy to use, very powerful, and really easy to style.